# Вставить символ в строку после определенного количества символов

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
$str = 'Маша мыла раму';
```

Мне нужно после 7-го символа (включая пробелы) вставить символ **|**

Но чтобы не разрывало слово. То есть, должно получиться:

```
Маша | мыла раму
```

или

```
Маша мыла | раму
```

буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: вот сивол у вас в слове куда его переносить? в начало или конец/

Comment: @Naumov не совсем понял вопроса

Comment: Ну вот символ "|" по середине слова куда его надо перенести?

Comment: Отступаете 7 символов, ищете первый пробел, вставляете палку с пробелом. Где проблемы-то возникли?

Comment: В общем проголосовал за закрытие ибо вопрос похож на какое то тестовое задание.

Comment: @splash58 а если пробел нужно искать не следующий а который был перед словом (чтобы на выходе получился второй вариант приведенный в вопросе). можно пример реализации в коде? там как, регуляркой?)

Comment: @Naumov в начало слова

Comment: я вас не понимаю. какой смысл в словах *после 7-го символа* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Отступаете 7 символов, ищете первый пробел, вставляете палку с пробелом

```
$str = 'Маша мыла раму';
$offset = 7;

$pos = mb_strpos($str, " ", $offset - 1);

$result = mb_substr($str, 0, $pos) . " |" . mb_substr($str, $pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не тестил, но ход мысли думаю понятен (решение "на коленке")

```
$str = 'Маша мыла раму';
$arrStr = explode(' ', $str);
$counter = 0;
$newArray = [];
$trigger = true;
foreach($arrStr as $word){
    $counter += strlen($word) + 1;
    if ( $counter >= 7 && $trigger == true) {
        $newArray []= $word . ' |';
        $trigger = false;
    } else {
        $newArray []= $word;
    }
}
$result = implode(' ', $newArray);
echo $result;
```

p.s. учитывайте что кирилица и латиница имеет разную длину символов

Comment: а если вместо триггера break ?

Comment: ну тогда "улетит" оставшаяся часть строки что после слеша

Comment: естественно надо cчитать индекс, и либо брать остаток массива, либо заменить в нем один элемент x[i] = '| '.x[i]

Comment: Как писал выше, это "ход мысли", как это можно сделать. Если ТС подходит решение, то пусть берет и оптимизурует. Заодно и разберется.

Comment: с этим я спорить не буду :)

Answer (score -1):

Опубликую ответ как самое короткое решение

```
$result = str_replace(' ', ' | ', $word);
```

так как если переносим в начало слова мы в любом случае попадаем в пробел